Is optimistic locking safe from race condition in case of concurrent transactions?
When reading about optimistic locks, I have come across examples which use versioning like below
UPDATE table SET column1 = new_value1, version = version + 1 WHERE id = some_id AND version = old_version

I am not able to understand how it is absolutely safe. If two concurrent transactions read the same old version during update and then both proceed to update column1 and version we will have incorrect update here. Unless both WHERE and SET operations are atomic at the database level(that is transaction does read and update atomically in one go), one transaction can read old version and but before it updates the new version, another transaction can also read same old version and then both will proceed to update the version leading to incorrect update.
What am I missing here? How is this handled in SQL Server?

@MartinSmith Is it correct to say that optimistic locking in SQL server is using locks and its not exactly lock-free as is the impression I get when I read articles about optimistic locking?

Surprised that the question is closed. Its asking about one problem only. Which part of it is not focused?

Asking about three different RDBMSs

It's also not really programming related; it would be on topic for [dba.se], but likely you would need  to focus on a single RDBMS.

My earlier comment that SQL Server will still take U locks when finding the row at TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT is not correct. It still takes an X lock when updating the row but not a U lock on the read. What actually happens is that you end up seeing error "Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict." in the second transaction as soon as the first transaction commits. You can easily reproduce this in SSMS by opening two transactions at snapshot isolation level in different windows then running the update in both and finally a commit in the one not blocked

Read committed snapshot does still take the U lock though

The database server simply won't allow the situation that you describe; two concurrent transactions won't be allowed to make conflicting writes.
The exact details depend both on the implementation and on various transaction settings, but a typical pattern is that if transaction X has written to a given row, and transaction Y tries to write to the same row, then transaction Y will block until transaction X has either been committed or rolled back; and if transaction X ends up being committed, then transaction Y will re-verify that the condition is still met before it performs the write.
You may be interested in database transaction conflict resolution, which goes into some more detail about certain aspects of this.

"if transaction X has written to a given row, and transaction Y tries to write to the same row, then transaction Y will block until transaction X has either been committed or rolled back; and if transaction X ends up being committed, then transaction Y will fail"
Does this happen for Read Committed isolation level too in any relational DB?

and if transaction X ends up being committed, then transaction Y will fail - this must definitely be implementation-specific, because SQL Server doesn't behave like this, afair. (Not under default settings anyway)

@RogerWolf It does if you use snapshot isolation. Under the other isolation levels, pessimistic locking is used so you would get blocked on the read phase.

@RogerWolf: You're right, I was thinking of a slightly different case. For this case, it looks like most RDBMSes will re-evaluate the condition; so the optimistic lock will fail (due to version mismatch), but transaction Y will go through (as a no-op). Will update.
